# RegExp match returning null despite working on a separate test file

Tags: javascript, regex, match

This is very weird, can't understand what is happening, on a separate test file I have the following and it works:

```
const title = 'apple iphone 8 prateado - smartphone 4.7 64gb 2gb ram hexa-core';
const model = 'iphone 8';
const regExString = "((\\s|^)"+model.trim()+"($|\\s|\\.)(?!GB))";
const regex = new RegExp(regExString, "gi");
const result = title.match(regex);
console.log(result);
```

The result prints ' iphone 8 ' as expected.

However in my process which has more code, it returns null, to make it work I had to do the following on my regExString:

```
const regExString = "((\\s|^)"+model.trim().replace(' ', '\\s')+"($|\\s|\\.)(?!GB))";
```

But I can't figure out why the hell I would need to add that in my node application, it should work with the space instead of the

> \\s

.

Any clues? Thanks

Comment: Your `model` probably contains a regular space (`\x20`), but the text contains a hard space, `\xA0`.

Comment: See what there in titl `/iphone(?=\s)(?![ ])([\S\s])/`

Comment: Not sure about the whitespace issue, but you could simplify this regex part `"((\\s|^)"` to `"\\b"`, e.g. on a word boundary, which includes start of string